# How to open the multiple .db file and insert all the rows of tables in live database using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, codeigniter

I have multiple this.db file in a folder which i want to open every one and insert the tables rows in to my live database as sync process. i can do for only one db file using construct but when i use for each  it does not works for multiple db file.this.db file is the sqlite database file that i upload from android app.Please help me here. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution myself. Use this if you have the same problem:

```
public function index() {
    $dir = 'db';
    $db = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($db as $key => $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            var_dump($file);
            $filename = 'db/'.$file;
            var_dump($filename);
            $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $filename);
            $result = $file_db->query('SELECT * FROM image');
            $result1 = $file_db->query('SELECT * FROM initial_details');
            foreach ($result as $m) {
                var_dump($m);
            }
            foreach ($result1 as $m1) {
                var_dump($m1);
            }
            var_dump($result);
        }
    }
    die();
    $this->load->view('users_view');
}
```